# Why is git looking inside vendors directory?

Tags: ruby, git, gitignore

I have the .gitignore file with this code:

```
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
/app/bootstrap*
/vendor/*
/web/bundles/
/app/config/parameters.yml
```

but when I do :

```
$ git status
```

in any situation (before and after add and commit), I get a long text output like this:

```
    ...

    #   deleted:    vendor/doctrine/orm/tools/sandbox/cli-config.php
    #   deleted:    vendor/doctrine/orm/tools/sandbox/doctrine
    #   deleted:    vendor/doctrine/orm/tools/sandbox/doctrine.php
    #   deleted:    vendor/doctrine/orm/tools/sandbox/index.php
    #   deleted:    vendor/doctrine/orm/tools/sandbox/xml/Entities.Address.dcm.xml
    #   deleted:    vendor/doctrine/orm/tools/sandbox/xml/Entities.User.dcm.xml
    #   deleted:    vendor/doctrine/orm/tools/sandbox/yaml/Entities.Address.dcm.yml
    #   deleted:    vendor/doctrine/orm/tools/sandbox/yaml/Entities.User.dcm.yml
    #   modified:   vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle
    #   modified:   vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions
    #   modified:   vendor/herzult/forum-bundle/Herzult/Bundle/ForumBundle
    #   modified:   vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic
    #   modified:   vendor/symfony/property-access/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/.gitignore
    #   modified:   vendor/symfony/property-access/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/StringUtil.php
    #   modified:   vendor/symfony/symfony/CHANGELOG-2.1.md

    ...
```

The vendors directory is in .gitignore file, so I don't know what is happening.
I've tried with:

```
$ sudo git clean -dxf
```

but nothing changes.

Comment: Honest question: in `.gitignore` does one really put a leading slash for directories git should ignore? It seems like it should be `./ignored_directory/*` or just `ignored_directory/*` otherwise it will ignore the directory on root, which likely doesn't exist?

Comment: @erewok putting just vendor will remove all folders or files named vendor

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Your vendor directory is checked in to the repo. To remove it, go to your git repo root and run:

```
git rm -r --cached vendor
```

This will recursively (due to `-r` flag) remove vendor from your git repo. The `--cached` flag will keep the local copy of vendor directory in tact. Note that if there are other devs working with the repo, their copy of the `vendor` directory will be removed and they will need to `bundle install` again.

Once you've untracked the directory in git, you can commit the change using:

```
git commit -m "untrack vendor directory"
```

Thereafter, `.gitignore` will happily ignore any changes within the vendor directory next time onwards.

Also, you don't need your entries in `.gitignore` to begin with a `/`. Use the `/` when you want to ensure that only files/folders in root directory are ignored, and any file in a subdirectory matching the pattern should not be ignored.

Comment: You don't _need_ your entries in .gitignore to begin with a `/`, but please note that it can lead to unexpected results. The leading slash matches the root of your repository. If you don't use it, *every* folder called `vendor` will be ignored.

Comment: Also I think it's useful to explain that `--cached` is used to let git remove the files from the repository, but let them remain in your local working copy.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you already have files under vendor/* checked in. `.gitignore` ignores only untracked files. See also the first paragraph in `man gitignore`.